# Castle Windsor IoC inject Property into Constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have a session manager class that has a session property.  I need to pass that into another class as a constructor parameter.  How should I configure the installer for castle windsor?

e.g.

```
public interface ISessionManager
{
    ISession CurrentSession { get; set; }
}

public class SessionManager : ISessionManager
{
    private ISession _session;
    public ISession CurrentSession
    {
        get { return _session ?? (_session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession()); }
        set { _session = value; }
    }
}

public interface IRequest
{
    TR Execute<TR>(IExecuteManager<TR> executeManager);
}

public class Request: IRequest
{
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public Request(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }
    public TR Execute<TR>(IExecuteManager<TR> executeManager)
    {
        return executeManager.Request(_session);
    }
}
```

I've been rooting around in the castle windsor docs but I must be searching for the wrong thing or missing something, because I'm sure it is there, just can't find it.

How should I configure the castle windsor installer so that the SessionManager.CurrentSession is injected into the Request class' constructor?  (ref to correct windsor doc or example is totally fine too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
container.Register(Component.For<ISession>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(() => container
        .Resolve<ISessionManager>().CurrentSession)
    .LifeStyle.Transient);
```

Comment: I changed IService to ISession and was all good.  Thanks!  I was totally on the wrong track as far as what docs I was referencing for this, but now I'm straightened out.