# Inject one class into another using Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Say I have a the following casses:

```
public class ClassA : IClassA
{
   //Contains methods
}

public interface IClassA
{
   //Contains methods
}
```

The Castle Windsor definition would look like this:

```
public class ServiceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
        public void Install(Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer container,
        Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Component.For<IClassA>().ImplementedBy<ClassA>());
    }
}
```

Now say I wanted to add this class to the project:

```
public class ClassB : IClassB
{
   private IClassA classA

   public ClassA (IClassA classA)
   {
      this.classA=classA;
   }
}

public interface IClassB
{
   //Contains methods
}
```

How can I configure Castle Windsor to create ClassB classes? I believe I have two options:

1) Configure CastleWindosor to create instances of ClassB with ClassA injected.  ClassA should be created before it is injected into ClassB.

2) Add a zero arguement constructor to ClassB and remove the current constructor.  Then use setter injection to inject ClassA into ClassB.

I am hoping I can use option 1.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304364/castle-windsor-ioc-inject-property-into-constructor?rq=1

Comment: Maybe i don't understand your question, but when you register both classes, you can easily resolve `IClassB` like you would resolve `IClassA`. Castle.Windsor injects `IClassA` automatically in `ClassB`. This is the main purpose of Dependency Injection.

Comment: @Rabban, I realise that, however ClassB members have default values.  I need them to be constructed.

Comment: Your code doesn't show any default values. Can you please clearify your question, i still don't understand the issue.